# Meteor packages dynamic imports fail with templating as weak dependency

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, dynamic-import, meteor-packages

### The Package

I have a shared library as Meteor package with the following structure:

```
ui
  - componentA.html
  - componentA.js
  - loader.js
  - ...
tools
  - toolXY.js
  - ...
```

and while `tools` are shared among many of my apps (and the ui), the `ui` part is only used by one app. Consider the template to be totally simple:

*componentA.html*

```html
<template name="componentA">
  <span>yea component A</span>
</template>
```

*componentA.js*

```js
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating'
import { toolXY } from '../tools/toolXY'
import './componentA.html'

// ... template code
```

*loader.js (little helper, think the package has 100 ui components)*

```js
export const loader = {
  componentA: {
    template: 'componentA',
    load: async function () {
      return import('./componentA')
    }
  }
}
```

Because the ui is used in one app only, I made the `templating` and `dynamic-import` a weak dependency:

```js
Package.onUse(function (api) {
  api.versionsFrom('1.6')
  api.use('ecmascript')
  api.use('dynamic-import', ['client'], { weak: true })
  api.use('templating', ['client'], { weak: true })
})
```

### The Problem

I add my package and the weak dependencies to a project via

```sh
$ meteor add dynamic-import templating me:mypackage
```

and import the ui on the client like the following:

*client/main.js*

```js
import { loader } from 'meteor/me:mypackage/ui/loader'

Meteor.startup(() => {
  loader.componentA.load()
    .then(() => console.log('loaded'))
    .catch(e => console.error(e))
})
```

It will result in the following error:

```
Error: "Cannot find module './componentA.html'"
    makeMissingError http://localhost:5050/packages/modules-runtime.js?hash=23fe92393aa44a7b01bb53a510a9cab5fb43037c:232
    resolve http://localhost:5050/packages/modules-runtime.js?hash=23fe92393aa44a7b01bb53a510a9cab5fb43037c:238
    moduleLink http://localhost:5050/packages/modules.js?hash=88e9e724ccc8459066fbe9e3889ef37c7bb7067f:353
    module /node_modules/meteor/me:mypackage/ui/componentA.js:16
    makeModuleFunction http://localhost:5050/packages/dynamic-import.js?hash=cf582bcc349503492678c9fd3f7bba4a610f70e5:138
    fileEvaluate http://localhost:5050/packages/modules-runtime.js?hash=23fe92393aa44a7b01bb53a510a9cab5fb43037c:346
    require http://localhost:5050/packages/modules-runtime.js?hash=23fe92393aa44a7b01bb53a510a9cab5fb43037c:248
    moduleLink http://localhost:5050/packages/modules.js?hash=88e9e724ccc8459066fbe9e3889ef37c7bb7067f:360
    getNamespace http://localhost:5050/packages/dynamic-import.js?hash=cf582bcc349503492678c9fd3f7bba4a610f70e5:187
    dynamicImport http://localhost:5050/packages/dynamic-import.js?hash=cf582bcc349503492678c9fd3f7bba4a610f70e5:40
```

Checking for `Package.templating` inside `loader.js`, as well as `componentA.js` resolves to `Object { Template: Template(viewName, renderFunction) }` (because it has been installed as package to the project).

### The fix that isn't really a fix

If I turn off the weak dependency on `templating` it will work fine:

```js
api.use('templating')
```

This, however, will cause all my applications to load `templating`, allthough they do not require it.

### The question

Why is it behaving like this? Shouldn't this work with weak dependency when the dependency has been added to the project?

Comment: are you sure the difference in your non-solution is not the fact that you are now including templating on the server as well (rather than just the omission of the 'weak')? I would expect templating to be required on the server for the necessary files to be served.

Comment: Are these local or through a private package server? I suspect the issue is in the package compilation step, rather than during app runtime. Also, have you tried using deep imports for the component instead of the loader? `import 'meteor/me:mypackage/ui/componentA'`